# Respond.js causes IE8 Crash

Tags: javascript, html, media-queries, respond.js

http://dev.netcoding.net/lowsglass/about-us/

I've been attempting to get [Respond.js](https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond) to work in IE8 but it's causing a crash before I can get anything out of of the Developer Tools.

I switched from the minified version to the original to help assist in the debugging.

Comment: Can you try the respond.js crash test on your ie?[Test](http://scottjehl.github.com/Respond/test/unit/) @BrianGraham

Comment: @SamDroid http://dev.netcoding.net/i/53d4516f14.png

Comment: add the latest version, make sure you don't use nth child selector, don't use max-height and also make sure you don't get strange html structures that make the ie to freak out.